# How to escape text for regular expression?

Tags: java

How to escape text for regular expression?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can [edit] your question, don't add informations in comments.

Answer (score 0):

For decimal digit, you can use `\d+(\.\d+)*` regex. If we put it into the context of the statement, we get this:

```
(\\d+(\\.\\d+)*)+\\)\\((\\d+(\\.\\d+)*)+
```

Here's an example:

```
String s = "10.0)(20.0";
String regex = "(\\d+(\\.\\d+)*)+\\)\\((\\d+(\\.\\d+)*)+";
System.out.println(s.matches(regex));
```

Comment: I have tried with Java only, but you can test it for other languages.

Comment: Added an example in the answer. You need to escape the back slashes.

Comment: Could you post an error instead of attaching to the answer.